# How to make a game board

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm just starting with iOS game development and I'm going to start with a simple board game.  How can I create an 8x8 game board?  The board will end up being a maze with objects in certain squares of the board.  I want to select a maze then have the game board created with obstacles in certain locations.

Comment: The question is pretty vague.  Are you asking about graphics, or data structures, or...?

Comment: Both.  I'm just not really sure how to go about it.  I'm thinking of actually having the game board on an image view to give it the look I want.

Comment: Look into using SpriteKit. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html

Answer (score 0):

I always thought `UICollectionViewController` could make a pretty simple game board.

http://nscookbook.com/2013/02/ios-programming-recipe-14-implementing-a-uicollectionviewcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Graphics on a `UIView` to draw squares.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html